# Linear Integral in complex plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Integrate using Indefinite Integration and Substitution of Limits
Integration symbol with $c$ in denominator $ \mathrm{Re}(z) \, \mathrm{d}z $, $C$ the shortest path from $1 + i$ to $5 +5i$.

Answer (score 0):

*To be honest I am not completely sure about the result so take it with a grain of salt. If you have suggestions or additions please notify me.*

**Hint.** Let $\gamma(t)=(1-t)(1+\mathrm i)+t(5+5\mathrm i)$ be our shortest path which is a basic linear interpolation with $t\in[0,1]$. Then use

$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt$$

with $f\equiv\operatorname{Re}$. For me this yields

$$\int_\gamma \operatorname{Re}(z)\,\mathrm dz=12(1+\mathrm i).$$

Comment: Could you add the complete solution please

Answer (score 0):

I am nervous that the way you ask this question indicates you really have no idea what the problem is about.  You stated the problem in words as
$$
    \frac{\int}{c} \operatorname{Re}(z)\,dz
$$
You should really go back and reread what path integrals of complex functions are, and how to evaluate them.  This is a very straightforward question and there should be plenty of examples available to mimic.  Things will only get harder from here.  If you are taking a course for credit, and hoping that asking for homework solutions online will enable you to succeed, the exam will be a very uncomfortable time for you.  As an instructor, I beg you to get help from your instructor.

The problem says to evaluate the integral with indefinite integration.  That is, we need a function of $z$ whose derivative with respect to $z$ is $\operatorname{Re}(z)$.  A hint is that 
$$
    \operatorname{Re}(z) = \frac{1}{2}(z+\bar z)
$$
Each of these can be integrated with respect to $z$, keeping in mind that $z$ and $\bar z$ are independent variables.  So
$$
    \int \operatorname{Re}(z)\,dz= \frac{1}{2}\int(z + \bar z)\,dz 
    = \frac{1}{2}(z^2 + \bar z z) = \frac12(z^2 + |z|^2)
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{split}
    \int\limits_C \operatorname{Re}(z)\,dz &= \left.\frac12(z^2 + |z|^2)\right|^{5+5i}_{1+i} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\left[((5+5i)^2 + |5+5i|^2)-((1+i)^2 + |1+i|^2)\right] \\
    &= 12 + 12i
\end{split}
$$
This agrees with Christian's answer.

Comment: I am sorry you feel nervous. I had to stop my graduation at 5th semester after my father died. I have been taking care of the family business. Now that my girlfriend has taken over the business, i m now back in college starting from 5th semester but i have forgotten everything i studied till now. This is me trying to regain the knowledge. All i need is some step by step illustration. I am not dumb, i m just old and haven't been able to study for 3 years. Thank you for the solution though, really appreciate it.

Comment: @user7286: That is, indeed, commendable.  I am sorry to hear of the loss of your father—that would be tough for any student.  I still think you should try to get some face-to-face help from your instructor/TA.  They have resources to help you get back on track.